# Logging profile updates in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, updates, profile, user-profile

I have a edit profile page in my social media website.

When users click submit on the form. I run an update query to obviously update the users field in the database.

How can I optimize this scenario to include the logging of which particular fields are updated?

So for e.g.

One scenario could be:

Chris updated his profile picture.

Another scenario would be:

Chris updated his profile, inc:

- Email
- Username
- Address
- Address 2

Can anyone offer a solution to this?

I feel there is no need for code as all it is, is an update query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When writing out the form, save the current states in the `$_SESSION`-variable. The check the submitted forms and compare with the data in the `$_SESSION`-variable. Then only make an update on the forms that have changed.

```
if($_SESSION['name'] != $myform['name']) { $sql[] = "name = '{$myform['name']}'"; }
if($_SESSION['img'] != $myform['img']) { $sql[] = "img = '{$myform['img']}'"; }
$sqlstring = "UPDATE mytable SET " . implode(",",$sql);
// run the sql
```

EDIT: to implement logging:

```
// populate the variables (name, img) from the db/session with the highest revision number.
// ie SELECT * FROM mytable where userid = $userid ORDER BY revision DESC LIMIT 1
$revision = $_SESSION['revision'] + 1;
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable SET img = '$img', name='$name', revision='$revision'";
```

Comment: Right, so thats a way to only update the fields that need to be updated. Thats clear, I have not implemented that as of yet. What about the actual question, logging the changes? Should I make a seperate db table?

Comment: ah sorry. i'd just add add a revision number to the same table, and actually not make a update but add a new row with all the data as well as a higher revision number.

Comment: revision being the version of updates? say take revision 3, the latest rather than revision 1 the original updates?

Answer (score 0):

Did you put all that information in a `$_SESSION` or something? If so, you can unset the session and declare it again, with the new info.

Comment: yeah, all is in $_FORM[] a copy of $_SESSION

Comment: When the user updates, i assume it's in a form. So what you do, is unset the $_SESSION or $_FORM, and declare it again only with the posted values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom setters / getters to do this. Check the code below.

You can also add additional checks to make sure the values have changed, or use magic methods to make things more dynamic.

```
class MyObject
{
    protected $modifiedFields = array();
    public function setField($value) {
        if (!in_array('field', $this->modifiedFields)) {
            $this->modifiedFields[] = 'field';
        }
    }
}
```

If you have the modified fields, you can just run the update query to contain only these fields.